# Can't set \mathindent to 0pt

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsart

I am trying to make my equations completely flush to the left, along with the text. Even with \mathindent set to 0pt, there is still an indentation.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \underline{Impedance Z Parameters:}
    \[V_1 = z_{11}I_1 + z_{12}I_2\]
    \[V_2 = z_{21}I_1 + z_{22}I_2\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Please, add a [amsart] tag, because with `article` document class, you don't have this bug. If you add `\the\mathindent` after `\begin{document}` you will see it's actual value: 34.77783pt (in `amsart` document class), despite `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to move the line `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` after `\begin{document}`. I add here the package geometry only for demonstration purpose.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % for showing actual frame in this example; uncomment this line for your real paper
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
    \underline{Impedance Z Parameters:}
    \[V_1 = z_{11}I_1 + z_{12}I_2\]
    \[V_2 = z_{21}I_1 + z_{22}I_2\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've suggest to use `amsmath` and `\@mathmargin` instead of `\mathindent`, refer the below tags:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\@mathmargin{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \underline{Impedance Z Parameters:}
    \[V_1 = z_{11}I_1 + z_{12}I_2\]
    \[V_2 = z_{21}I_1 + z_{22}I_2\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@mathmargin` is a length not a macro, do not over-write it with `\def`, use `\setlength`